# Sell products together and separately

Tags: stock, inventory

i would like to sell bracelets. These bracelets have 3 parts. Band, clasp and a plate. I would like to sell them by parts and together, too. The price of the parts is not the same if i sell together or i sell separately.

Example: There is a bracelet with name EX1 bracelet. This EX1 bracelet has 3 different part. I sell separately PART1 for 1$, PART2 for $2 and PART3 for $3. Together (like a full bracelet) i sell for $5 This EX1 bracelet has 3 color variation. All parts have own SKU and all full bracelet have on SKU. In the inventory we have just parts, therefore if we sell a bracelet, we have to reduce just the parts stock of that bracelet.

Do you have any idea, how can i do that?

I tried with this: Parts are simple product. Full bracelets are configurable products with color options. In this case I cannot handle the parts inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check the possibility of such thing but the part that is configurable (color) needs to be a configurable. The other part simple products. The bracelet itself must be a bundle product. Normaly you can then choose the color of the bracelet even if you take the whole bracelet. You need to set the skus according to your needs and make all product visible on the scope you want.